# How to add RSA Signature to HTTP Request?

Tags: android

I'm writing a nodejs server to host a RESTful Service and an Android app that consumes those services.

The android app should sign its requests using RSA.

I've already done everything related to creating the key pairs and signing the message.

My problem is that I do not know how to send the signature to the server. At first I thought about simply adding a signature property to the request body, but quickly realized that wouldn't work, since that would be modifying the original message, preventing the server from verifying the signature.

So, how can I add a RSA signature to an http request on Android?

For reference, here's my Android code:

```
public final class MyCrypto {

    public static PublicKey generateRSAKeypair(Context context, String alias) throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableEntryException {

        // check if keypair already exists
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
        if (entry != null) {
            return ((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getCertificate().getPublicKey();
        }

        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                        .setKeySize(512)
                        .setAlias(alias)
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=something"))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                        .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                        .build());

        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

        return keyPair.getPublic();
    }

    public static void signRequest(String alias, JSONObject req) throws IOException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableEntryException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, JSONException {

        // get private key
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
        PrivateKey privateKey = ((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getPrivateKey();

        // sign message
        byte[] message = req.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        s.initSign(privateKey);
        s.update(message);
        byte[] signature = s.sign();

        // this doesnt work, because it changes the original message, thus preventing the server from validating the signature
        req.put("signature", Base64.encodeToString(signature , Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
}

public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        int responseCode = -1;

        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/endpoint");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2000);

            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

            urlConnection.connect();

            //Create JSONObject here
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("prop1", prop1);
            jsonParam.put("prop2", prop2);

            MyCrypto.signRequest(alias, jsonParam);

            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(jsonParam.toString());
            out.close();

            responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            String response;
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.d("connection", response);
            } else {
                response = readStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());
                Log.d("connection", response);
            }

            // delegate response processing to handler
            activity.handleResponse(responseCode, response);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (responseCode == -1) {
                String errorMessage = "Error connecting";
                activity.handleResponse(0, errorMessage);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if(urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add anything to the request via custom headers:

```
...
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("MyRSASignature", myRSASignature);
...
```

Comment: Thanks! In addition to this, I also had to add the NO_WRAP flag when encoding the signature to base64 string.

Comment: How to generate Signature for near by place api android?